# Objective-C Declaring NSMutableString

Tags: objective-c

I was wondering why can we declare NSString like this:

```
NSString *strongName            = @"Kuba";
```

But we cannot declare NSMutableString the same way:

```
NSMutableString *strongName2    = @"Kuba";
```

Instead, I have to use older(?) approach:

```
NSMutableString *strongName3 = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"Kuba"];
```

Thank you for any meaningful insight :))

Comment: Because `@"Kuba"` produces a `NSString`, it's non mutable. That's how it's done. Side note, you don't use format, so better use `stringWithString:` instead.

Comment: Also have a look in lldb what is the output of `po [strongName class]`  vs `po [strongName3 class]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSString *myString = @"Kuba"` is a shorthand for `NSString` alone. If you need a `NSMutableString`, you could get a mutable copy from it: `NSMutableString *myMutableString = [@"Kuba" mutableCopy]`.